# Downloading file from SFTP location using public key

Tags: bash, sshpass

Previously I downloaded a CSV file from an SFTP server using `SSHPASS` where the authentication method was through username/password and not public key:

```
sshpass -p [SFTP_SERVER_PASSWORD] sftp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss [USERNAME]@ftp1.exacttarget.com <<EOF
get -r /Export/MyFile.csv
EOF
```

The SFTP server has now added the public key (created on my Ubuntu server) and so I would like to change the command above to communicate without a password. What options should I add/remove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't need `sshpass` any longer, change your call to

```
sftp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss [USERNAME]@ftp1.exacttarget.com <<EOF
get -r /Export/MyFile.csv
EOF
```